# Java get integer value from string

Tags: java, string, integer

I'd like to get the integer value from my string. Below is my example.

```
String strScore = "Your score is 10. Probability in the next 2 years is 40%";
```

But I just want to get the score which is 10. How can I do this?

UPDATED:

```
String firstNumber = strScore.replaceFirst(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1");

bfLog.createEntry( firstNumber );
```

I save this to sqlite database.

Comment: `substring()` and `indexOf()`?

Comment: Is this string static? IE. is it always in this format?

Comment: Adding to Eng.Found - may be a regex with the logic, if you tell us what it is.

Comment: Hmm the only thing that changes in here is the score. Say the score is 26. And the next score is 7.

Comment: Hm then parse it till the dot, get the first part, then parse it again according to empty space get the last

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use one of the `String` regex `replace` methods to capture the first digits in a [captured group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html):

```
String firstNumber = strScore.replaceFirst(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1");
```

- `.*?` consumes initial non-digits(non-greedy)
- `(\\d+)` Get the one or more available digits in a group!
- `.*` Everything else (*greedy*).

Comment: can you explain a little bit the code you provided? Since I'd like to understand how this works. Thanks.

Comment: Okay but it still gets the next characters?

Comment: It matches on the remaining characters so that it "knows" where the initial digits are

Comment: `Strings` are immutable. Are you using the newly created `firstNumber` `Sting` rather than `strScore`?

Comment: Can't see how you could get that. If you want to add your code to the question...

Comment: Can't be sure what `createEntry` is doing. Can you print `firstNumber` first?

Comment: It's printing 9\nProbability in the next 2 years is 40%

Comment: All I can say is to check your input `String`. The above regex works with the format given in the question

Comment: I got the problem. Because I put newline character \n thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This depends on whether anything else can change in your string.

If it's always the same apart from the number, you can use

```
int score = Integer.parseInt(strScore.substring(14,16))
```

because the digits "10" are at index 14 and 15 of the string.
If other stuff changes in your string, you should use a regular expression :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Hmm, what if the score is only 7?

Comment: That will be OK because a space will be ignored afterwards.

Comment: well I still disagree, you cant be sure that the integer has less than two digits

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
String strScore = "Your score is 10. Probability in the next 2 years is 40%";
String intIndex = strScore.valueOf(10);
String intIndex = 10 // Result
```